# Allow spinner Increment/decrement by time interval TimePicker WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker, xceed-plus-edition

So I have a `TimePicker` declared in my XAML view file:

```
<xctk:TimePicker Grid.Column="5" Value="{Binding TimeFrame}" TimeInterval="00:30:0" Format="Custom" FormatString="HH:mm" Margin="3 3 3 0" MinWidth="100"/>
```

Which is binded to my `TimeFrame` method in my view model class:

```
private DateTime _timeFrame;
public DateTime TimeFrame
{
    get { return _timeFrame; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _timeFrame)
        {
            _timeFrame = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TimeFrame");
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, setting `TimeInterval` to `00:30:0` only shows those intervals in the dropdown.

Is there a way to also make the up/down spinner only increment/decrement by 30 mintues as well? Is there a way to register button presses with `TimePicker`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by subclassing the `TimePicker` and set the `Step` property to `30` whenever the minute part is increased or decreased:

```
public class CustomTimePicker : Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.TimePicker
{
    protected override void OnIncrement()
    {
        SetStep();
        base.OnIncrement();
    }

    protected override void OnDecrement()
    {
        SetStep();
        base.OnDecrement();
    }

    private void SetStep()
    {
        Step = CurrentDateTimePart == Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DateTimePart.Minute ? 30 : 1;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:CustomTimePicker Grid.Column="5" Value="{Binding TimeFrame}" 
                        TimeInterval="00:30:0" Format="Custom"
                        FormatString="HH:mm" 
                        Margin="3 3 3 0" MinWidth="100" />
```